# Can't $_POST with ckeditor

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm having trouble with CKEDITOR and i was hoping you could help me out.

I have this code inside a form tag:

```
        <div class="column column-1">
            <h3>Content</h3>
            <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" type="text"></textarea>
        </div>
```

I applied the next javascript to make the ckeditor work:

```
CKEDITOR.replace("editor1");
```

So far so good the editor is showing in my browser i can type in it and all that good stuff.

Now i tried to work with it using PHP:

```
echo $_POST['editor1'];
```

If the user submits the form it should echo `editor1`
The problem is its not happening. I tried to run multiple tests but its just not showing me anything. If i do the same with a normal textarea (not a ckeditor one) just the standard textarea it works. WHen i do it with ckeditor it wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this issue myself, I'm not sure my solution is 'best practice' but it does seem to work without issues.

What I've done is added an option-setting when initiating the editor to caputre the input content 'on change' and add it to your original textarea (which ckeditor will 'hide' before initiating itself).

The code:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        on : { 
            change: function ( evt )  {
              $('textarea[name="editor1"]').html(evt.editor.getData());
            }
        }
});
```

Notice the 'change' event-listener that updates the hidden text area.

Alternativly, you should be able to use the `getData()` function to retrieve the editor contents when the form is submitted (e.g. if you are using ajax etc.).

Hope this helps.